# How do I connect a IDE hard disk to a machine that only support SATA

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pci, pata

Given that IDE to USB2 converter is not allowed to be use, how do one connect a IDE hard disk to a machine that only support SATA hard disks and have PCI slots only and yet achieve the highest possible speed of reading and writing to the IDE hard disk.

The machine have SATA ports and PCI slots only. It does not have USB3 port. It have USB2 port but you cannot use it because you will likely not achieve the highest possible speed of reading and writing to the IDE hard disk.

Comment: Install a PCI IDE controller card.

Answer (score 0):

You can get IDE to SATA converters on ebay. Just search "IDE to SATA Converter" on ebay.

Comment: When using the IDE to SATA converters, will the speed be based on the IDE controller speed or the SATA controller speed?

Comment: I would assume IDE speed because the IDE chip on the hard drive would probably only be able to transfer at a max rate of 133MB/sec. This converter below in the link states it can transfer up to 480MB/sec The chip in the converter may be able to transfer at this rate however if the chip on the hard drive only accepts a max transfer rate of 133MB/sec then this is probably what you will get. http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/SATA-PATA-IDE-Drive-to-USB-2-0-Adapter-Converter-Cable-for-2-5-3-5-OK-/281617337081?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item4191b38af9

Comment: Take a look at http://www.diffen.com/difference/IDE_vs_SATA for speed comparison.